# GAE vs S3 for storing images/pictures

Tags: google-app-engine, amazon-s3, image

My webservice is running on GAE, and I am plan to provide feature to allow users to upload their pictures to share with others. To naturally GAE is my first resort for storing the pictures. But at the same time, I heard a lot good things about S3. I wonder if there is a comparison between the two in terms of storing images/pictures, cost, performance etc. Has anyone done that before?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Relative advantages of storage using Amazon Web Services S3 vs Google Application Engine](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/723469/relative-advantages-of-storage-using-amazon-web-services-s3-vs-google-application)

Comment: Is there a set of API that S3 provides for manipulating the pictures? and also, I assume that I need build a webservice running on S3 to accept the images from client side and return some sort of metadata?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

GAE rates for storing files: http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/quotas.html#Blobstore

S3 rates for storing files: http://aws.amazon.com/s3/pricing/

Answer (score 0):

You could also look into [Google Storage for Developers](http://code.google.com/apis/storage/), which is more of a direct competitor to Amazon's S3 than GAE is.

Comment: Good to know, but unfortunately, it seems still in preview stage.